# Qiskit's "Pulse" module: Sending a pulse to a qubit using a mock backend

Tags: qiskit, simulation

I'm trying to sende a pulse to a qubit on qiskit. I have succeeded in doing so when using a real backend on qiskit. But the trouble is, I can't get it to work on a mock backend.

I have tried a bunch of different things which I thought would, but none of them do. I've compiled my efforts in a pdf document accessible through the link below:

tan-shena-47.tiiny.site

I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Could you please share your code? This may help to identify your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome! As I wrote in my post, I've compiled my efforts in a pdf document accessible throught the following link: 

tan-shena-47.tiiny.site

However, I have since resolved the problem using an entirely different approach. Should I delete my post?

Comment: You can post your solution as answer. It may help others with similar issue. Just note that it is better to post the code as a part of the questions/answers to allow search machines find the post easily.